# Uncoupling membrane on new concrete

Tags: concrete, tile

Tiling my basement floor, but had a big heave in it from tree roots (tree now gone). I cut out all around the heave, removed old concrete, rebar’ed and jointed into old concrete and poured a new slab. Slab is 3-3.5” thick, rebar reinforced, 4 days cured now, curing with painter plastic laid over it.

**Question:** When  using stratamat uncoupling membrane , do I have to wait the full 28-day cure time before tiling over this new concrete?

I cannot find anything here or elsewhere on the web that addresses this question specifically.